# Sub Document operations in couchbase using .net sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, sdk, couchbase

### Delete a specific node from all the available documents in a bucket

Is it possible to delete an element from the children array based on the Id from the below sample document using .NET SDK for Couchbase in C#?

i.e. I need to delete all the details of Id=100( delete the entire element in the children array).

I can achieve it using N1QL. N1QL performance is slow when there are thousands of document involved in couchbase

```
{
    "results": [{
        "tutorial": {
            "type": "contact",
            "title": "Mr.",
            "fname": "Ian",
            "lname": "Taylor",
            "age": 56,
            "email": "ian@gmail.com",
            "children": [{
                    "Id": "100",
                    "Details": [{
                        "fname": "Abama",
                        "age": 17,
                        "gender": "F"
                    }]

                },
                {
                    "Id": "101",
                    "Details": [{
                        "fname": "Alex",
                        "age": 17,
                        "gender": "M"
                    }]

                }
            ],
            "hobbies": [
                "golf",
                "surfing"
            ],
            "relation": "cousin"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: SUBDOC operation,  requires document id and absolute path (not condition)

Comment: Detail answer https://forums.couchbase.com/t/sub-document-operations-using-net-sdk-c/29269